# Migrating App Engine project to Cloud NDB: local dev_appserver accessing production cloud rather than local datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm, dev-appserver

I am trying to migrate a Python 2.7 App Engine project from NDB to Cloud NDB as part of the migration process to Python 3.

After following the [Cloud NDB migration instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/standard/python/migrate-to-cloud-ndb), just running the dev_appserver as before now results in accessing the cloud rather than the local datastore. I see Google's [instructions for ensuring one accesses the local data](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/standard/python/migrate-to-cloud-ndb#testing), but I guess I don't understand how to use this in practice.

Assuming I have to use the datastore emulator to prevent this, I run dev_appserver with the flag `--support_datastore_emulator true`. This results in a successful conversion of my local datastore data into the sqllite format, but still queries the cloud.

I then set the required environment variables in app.yaml: DATASTORE_DATASET, DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID, DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST, DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH, DATASTORE_HOST (the values match the output of `gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init`).  Running it complains that DATASTORE_APP_ID is not set, so I set it as well.

Everything now launches with a confirmation message that the emulator is being used, but trying to access the datastore results in "BadArgumentError: Could not import googledatastore. This library must be installed with version >= 6.0.0 to use the Cloud Datastore API."  After installing that, I get a never-ending series of additional installation requirements and module conflicts... it's a mess, and this isn't listed in the documentation anyway.

How can I get dev_appserver (with or without the datastore emulator) to access local data rather than the cloud?  Sadly, I have now spent days trying to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (do it via terminal instead of specifying the environment variables in app.yaml).

1. Open a terminal and follow the instructions for starting your datastore emulator
2. After the emulator is up and running, **in a separate terminal**, run the `dev_appserver.py` command

If the above doesn't work, then 2 workarounds (have tested and confirmed these work)

1. Repeat the above steps but start your python app without `dev_appserver.py`. I tested this with Flask and it worked (I tested this with our [App](https://nocommandline.com) but that's the underlying code for the feature that I used in the test)
2. Second option is to use Bundled API for NDB (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access) for setting it up). If you go this route, then you don't need to explicitly start/enable the datastore emulator. This method will automatically use local datastore when you're not running in Production and will connect to production data when you're running on google cloud

Comment: really appreciate the response. I didn't list the many things I tried over the past few days, but I did try running the dev_appserver and the emulator in separate windows, to no avail (they connected, but queries still went to the cloud).  I just tried your workaround 1, and trying to run the python app from Flask without invoking the dev_appserver just errors out, complaining about missing modules.  And option 2 will only be viable once I complete the port to Python 3.

Comment: Are you able to share some of the missing modules it's complaining about?

Comment: With all my experimenting, @NoCommandLine, I have now completely bollixed this environment.  Rather than try to recreate, I'm going to skip ahead to the full Python 3 implementation.  But I'm already running into issues trying to understand best way to run/debug locally.  Would love an answer to [this question on dev environment recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852788/how-to-test-run-debug-non-legacy-app-engine-project-using-pycharm-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to

```
ndb.Client(gae_project_name)
```

is the project name.  I set this to a different value when running locally to ensure that I don't accidentally access production.